# REST API versioning in Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, api-design, bootstrapping

I wanted to make versioning like a domain. So inside app directory i want to move all folders into v1, v2, etc. So it will be App\v1, App\v2 namespaces. I need an advice, how to re-write bootstrap/app.php file, to instruct laravel to load only providers needed for the particular version. Where to put admin panel ? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: i want to be able to load only needed providers for each version.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify the bootstrap classes, instead go with this structure for API:

```
App
  Http
    Api
      V1
        -ApiController.php
 Controllerphp
 OtherWebController.php
```